# Debugging using Xcode

Tags: macos, xcode4

This question might be trivial or duplicate.
I am on Mac OS X. I have an exe (.app for Mac OS X) compiled using makefile without Xcode.
I want to debug this application using Xcode. (Application can be debugged as it is compiled using -g option).
Now, I want to debug this exe using Xcode. How to do this in Xcode?

In Windows using Visual Studio, I can open exe under Visual Studio using "devenv application" and then debug.

How can this be achieved in Mac OS X system?

I am using Xcode 4.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did in following way:

1. Create an empty project under Xcode.
2. Under Product > New Scheme, add a scheme.
3. Under Run, choose the exe or application.

Now, put the break points and run the exe.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! It works. I've been googling for this for more than half an hour, there is plenty of solutions coming up before this one, but they seem to be all not up to date with latest XCode...